# Change the dist-folder path in angular-cli after 'ng build'

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In Angular CLI, how I can change the path of the `dist` *folder*?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can update the output folder in .angular-cli.json:

```
"outDir": "./location/toYour/dist"
```

Comment: Is it possible to put index.html in ./location/toYour/dist and javascript bundles in a sub folder e.g. ./location/toYour/dist/bundles

Comment: Anyone know of any updates on customising the outDir further? css/ ts/ in separate paths

Comment: @fidev have a look at the "output" key for assets, should at least work for css files

Comment: This answer does not work in Angular 6+ anymore. The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50879251/10696285) below is better.

Comment: The file is `angular.json` for newer Angular versions.

Answer (score 261):

The more current way of this is to update the `outDir` property in `angular.json`(called `.angular-cli.json` in old Angular CLI versions).

The `ng build` command argument `--output-path` (or `-op` for short) is still supported also, which can be useful if you want multiple values, you can save them in your `package.json` as npm scripts.

> **Beware:** The `.angular-cli.json` property is NOT called `output-path` like the [currently-accepted answer by @cwill747](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37351526/146656) says. That's the `ng build` argument only.
>
> It's called `outDir` as mentioned above, and it's a under the `apps` property.

.

#### P.S.

(December 2017)

**1-year after adding this answer**, someone added a new answer with essentially same information, and the Original Poster changed the accepted answer to the 1-year-late answer containing same information in the first line of this one.

Comment: Is it possible to put index.html in ./location/toYour/dist and JavaScript bundles in a sub folder e.g. ./location/toYour/dist/bundles

Comment: he is probably promoting his friend here, this is a corruption

Answer (score 119):

For Angular 6+ things have changed a little.

## Define where ng build generates app files

Cli setup is now done in **angular.json** (replaced .angular-cli.json) in your workspace root directory. The output path in default angular.json should look like this (irrelevant lines removed):

```
{
  "projects": {
    "my-app-name": {
    "architect": {
      "options": {
         "outputPath": "dist/my-app-name",
```

Obviously, this will generate your app in WORKSPACE/dist/my-app-name. Modify outputPath if you prefer another directory.

You can overwrite the output path using command line arguments (e.g. for CI jobs):

```
ng build -op dist/example
ng build --output-path=dist/example
```

S.a. https://angular.io/cli/build

## Hosting angular app in subdirectory

Setting the output path, will tell angular where to place the "compiled" files but however you change the output path, when running the app, angular will still assume that the app is hosted in the webserver's document root.

To make it work in a sub directory, you'll have to set the base href.

In angular.json:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "my-app-name": {
    "architect": {
      "options": {
         "baseHref": "/my-folder/",
```

Cli:

```
ng build --base-href=/my-folder/
```

If you don't know where the app will be hosted on build time, you can change base tag in generated index.html.

Here's an example how we do it in our docker container:

entrypoint.sh

```
if [ -n "${BASE_PATH}" ]
then
  files=( $(find . -name "index.html") )
  cp -n "${files[0]}" "${files[0]}.org"
  cp "${files[0]}.org" "${files[0]}"
  sed -i "s*<base href=\"/\">*<base href=\"${BASE_PATH}\">*g" "${files[0]}"
fi
```

Comment: The first options for changing the output path dont work. -op and --output-path give a `Unknown option: '--output-path'` message

Comment: @MartijnHiemstra - tested with angular cli 13 and it works. What's the command you've tried?

Comment: Thanks, that worked pretty well. Since I've got my app running in a subdirectory like http://myserver.com/TheSubDirectory I simply used ```./``` as the ```baseHref```. Now I can name the ```TheSubDirectory``` however I like and it always works

Comment: This is the answer over all the others. Including WHERE `outputPath` goes within the angular config is required information. Bonus pts too for the additional details.

Comment: Every example/tutorial for multi projects I've found missed this minor detail. Thank you.

Answer (score 56):

You can use the CLI too, like:

```
ng build -prod --output-path=production

# or

ng serve --output-path=devroot
```

Comment: Is it possible to overwrite output dir in **angular-cli.json** ?

Comment: Looks like this feature is going in with this pull request: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1109

Answer (score 19):

The only thing that worked for me was to change `outDir` in in both `angular-cli.json` AND `src/tsconfig.json`.

I wanted my dist-folder outside the angular project folder. If I didn't change the setting in `src/tsconfig.json` as well, Angular CLI would throw warnings whenever I build the project.

Here are the most important lines ...

```
// angular-cli.json
{
  ...
  "apps": [
    {
      "outDir": "../dist",
      ...
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

And ...

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Update for `cli 7x`, the above is done in `angular.json` and the field is `outputPath` (`tsconfig`  adjustment above remains the same). Hth

Answer (score 17):

> **Beware:** The correct answer is below. This no longer works

Create a file called `.ember-cli` in your project, and include in it these contents:

```
{
   "output-path": "./location/to/your/dist/"
}
```

Answer (score 15):

for github pages I Use

```
ng build --prod --base-href "https://<username>.github.io/<RepoName>/" --output-path=docs
```

This is what that copies output into the docs folder : `--output-path=docs`

Answer (score 9):

Angular CLI now uses environment files to do this.

First, add an `environments` section to the `angular-cli.json`

Something like :

```
{
  "apps": [{
      "environments": {
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }]
}
```

And then inside the environment file (`environments/environment.prod.ts` in this case), add something like :

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  "output-path": "./whatever/dist/"
};
```

now when you run :

```
ng build --prod
```

it will output to the `./whatever/dist/` folder.

Comment: Looks like the best answer, but Angular CLI still publishes my files in the dist-folder. Version: `angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.21`

Comment: From Angular CLI [Wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli):
_outDir (string): The output directory for build results. Default is dist/._

Comment: @hbthanki Thats the cli switch, not the environment file json property

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to set the webroot path to the angular cli dist folder.
In your Program.cs when configuring the WebHostBuilder just say

```
.UseWebRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Frontend\\dist")
```

or whatever the path to your dist dir is.

Answer (score 1):

### **Caution: Angular 6 and above!**

---

For readers with an `angular.json` (not `angular-cli.json`) the key correct key is *outputPath*. I guess the angular configuration changed to `angular.json` in Angular 6, so if you are using version 6 or above you most likely have a `angular.json` file.

To change the output path you have to change *outputPath* und the build options.

example `angular.json`

```json
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "projects": {
        "angular-app": {
            "projectType": "application",
            [...]
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/angular-app",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        [...]
```

I could not find any official docs on this (not included in https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config as I would have expected), maybe someone can link an official resource on this.

Comment: I did this and it doesnt work. I get the error:  ```Schema validation failed with the following errors:   Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(outputPath).
```