# Custom path for angular-cli.json file path?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Can we provide the path for `angular-cli.json` to `ng build`, right now it doesn't seem to be supported.

Update:

What i am looking for is if we can have multiple `angular-cli.json` file with different name and that can be fed to `ng build command` something like

```
ng build --path\--config angular-cli-123.json
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple apps are now [supported out of the box](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps).

> Angular CLI support multiple applications within one project. You use
>   the apps array in .angular-cli.json to list files and folders you want
>   to use for different apps.

```
"apps": [
  {
    "root": "src",
    ...
    "main": "main.ts",
    "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
    "test": "test.ts",
    "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
    "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
    "prefix": "app",
    ...
  },
  {
    "root": "src",
    ...
    "main": "main2.ts",
    "polyfills": "polyfills2.ts",
    "test": "test2.ts",
    "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
    "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
    "prefix": "app2",
    ...
  }  
]
```

To serve the first app: ng serve --app=0 or ng serve --app 0

To serve the second app: ng serve --app=1 or ng serve --app 1

Hope it helps, someone!!

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348045/how-to-change-the-dist-folder-path-in-angular-cli-after-ng-build) might help.

> Create a file called .ember-cli in your project, and include in it
>   these contents:
>
> {    "output-path": "./location/to/your/dist/" }

Comment: Thanks for this,but it doesnt help, I have updated my question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an `angular-cli.json` file to `ng build`, but you can pass `--output-path`.

I'd store multiple npm scripts in my `package.json` file like:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "build:123": "ng build --output-path \"dist-123\"",
  "build:456": "ng build --output-path \"dist-456\"",
}
```

Comment: The reason i need multiple `angular-cli.json` is, I have multiple apps with different configuration like src location of test scripts etc, I want to build them based upon there configuration. i can use --output-path for different output location, but the need is to build multiple apps using differnt src folders. Thanks!

Comment: I'd just use multiple Angular CLI projects for these to be honest.