# Trying to understand the file structure in angular 7 app

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I got a solution and instructed to run by `npm run build` and then 'gulp dist'.

Here is the structure of the solution folders:

[image]

If I run the pixie -> index.html file in browser, my full app runs fine.

the full app is in the sibling folder source. that means `source` is the application folder. I run all ng commands in `source` folder.

source -> src -> app -> ....

But if I run it by `ng-serve`, another html file which is in

source -> dist -> angular -> index.html location, runs.

I wanted to understand the structure, and how do I make change and make impact in the **pixie -> index.html** file? because, whatever change I make, that does not effect the pixie -> index.html

Package.json

```
 {
  "name": "pixie2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --aot --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng build --prod --source-map --deploy-url=assets/",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.0",
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.3.2",
    "@ngxs/logger-plugin": "^3.3.2",
    "@ngxs/schematics": "0.0.1-alpha.5",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.3.2",
    "b64-to-blob": "^1.2.19",
    "canvas": "^2.5.0",
    "copy-to-clipboard": "^3.0.8",
    "core-js": "^2.6.2",
    "deepmerge": "^3.0.0",
    "dot-object": "^1.7.1",
    "fabric": "^2.6.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "hex-rgb": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^7.3.0",
    "node-gyp": "^4.0.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "raven-js": "^3.27.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.2",
    "url-polyfill": "^1.1.3",
    "webfontloader": "^1.6.28",
    "zone.js": "0.8.27"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.0",
    "@ngxs/schematics": "^0.0.1-alpha.5",
    "@types/deepmerge": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/dot-object": "^1.5.0",
    "@types/fabric": "file:./fabric-types",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.35",
    "@types/node": "~10.12.18",
    "@types/stripe-v3": "^3.0.9",
    "@types/webfontloader": "^1.6.29",
    "chartist": "^0.11.0",
    "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-filter": "^5.1.0",
    "gulp-hub": "^4.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-svg-sprite": "^1.5.0",
    "gulp-svgmin": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-svgstore": "^7.0.1",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.12.1",
    "typescript": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

From the pixie directory, I am running the app fine: 
[image]

But the localhost:4200 has a different version. how do i match them?
[image]

Comment: What's your `package.json` you can simple run the app by doing `ng serve --open` from the root folder of the app (where `package.json` is present ). Do your changes and save and then you can build the app with `ng build` from the same location you will notice your dist folder gets regenerated with your recent changes.

Comment: There should be `index.html` under `src` no? Or am I misunderstanding something

Comment: @SouravDutta I have added package.json

Comment: You could do npm start from root folder to run your app locally

Answer (score 0):

There is a production version and a development version of the site.

The pixie/ folder was created as the result of an `ng build` command. It is the production version of the site. On `ng build` your TypeScript files are transpiled into Javascript and minified. It's the little, just what you need to run version of the site.

Comment: which .js file? runtime.xxxxxxx.js / main.xxxxxx.js this types of js files?
how can I regenerate that build production? i tried production build. but nothing changed.

Comment: Did you try "ng build"? It should have created a new folder called dist/ that looks like your pixie/ folder.

Comment: ya that is tried. and i can run it fine. but the version loads there is corrupted anyway. The file I indicating which is little outside the source, (index.html) runs absoutely fine.

Comment: It looks like you are using Ahead-Of-Time (AOT) compiler https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler What does your dist/ folder look like?

Comment: dist -> angular -> assets -> ...  AND index.html, main.xxxx.js, polyfills.xxxx.js., runtime.xxxxx.js, styles.xxxx.css and Final folder also contains same files

Comment: In .angular-cli.json you can set the output directory for "ng build" see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348045/how-to-change-the-dist-folder-path-in-angular-cli-after-ng-build you can also "ng build --output-path=pixie"

Comment: Finally I could run from 4200 with `ng serve --aot` Thanks