# Angular code not running on server after deployment on server

Tags: angular

i am getting blank screen

in console below errors showing
runtime.06daa30….js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
polyfills.f6ae3e8….js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

help me please

Comment: Are you running your app in a sub directory? If yes: Set base path, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348045/how-to-change-the-dist-folder-path-in-angular-cli-after-ng-build/50879251#50879251

Comment: Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example or add more detailed code snippets on what you have tried. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically a server issue. The files are not at the place where the script tag in the HTML points to. Are you sure the server config is correct? Is the path really correct?